# Protect cached content in apache

Tags: security, apache-2.4, cache, token

I'm facing an issue where I have some cached contents in a disk and I want to protect it with a token url.

I can protect my files via htaccess, once they are not cached (direct access), but now I need to protected files that are in cache.

Anyone can light my way on this? Thanks.

Comment: you serve the cache?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm woking on the cache side and the origin side.